# How to use saveAll method provided by spring data crudRepository with uniqueKey constraint?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

In my parent entity while I am having a list of child entity which maintain a unique key constraint (the parent id itself) how can I use saveAll method in this particular case?

As we know without doing flush the changes are not reflected within the transaction so the parents don't have their ids before commit.

So for now I am doing saveAndFlush in a loop for each of my parent entity. Or is there any better approach besides this?

Comment: I don't understand the question. How do child entities maintain a unique key? Why should it matter if you call `save` or `saveAll`? Unique keys are maintained by the database, not by JPA or Spring Data JPA.

Comment: #1. Unique key = child table's one particular column + reference column for parent id
#2. While doing save all, id is not assigned immediately untill commit happens, so child table has null in place of the parent reference id column, as it is the part of the unique key columns - multiple inserts without doing flush for each one individually raises duplicate data exception.

Comment: There are lots of questions about foreign keys being `null` with JPA. Check those out. If none describes your problem, please update your question with the entities code, what exactly you are doing, the schema and the exception you are getting.

Comment: A quick fix are deferred constraints if your database supports them.